# How to add several "input fields" as an object or array

Tags: database, laravel, forms

I am designing CRM for photographers and I need help with a problem.
I have a table "orders" with orders from clients, and a table "photo_prints" where I store data with types of photographic prints (columns: paper_size, paper_type, price).
I need to add a certain amount of "input fields" in the "create order" form, depending on how many types of prints the customer chooses and save it to the database as e.g. an array or object. The fields must be of the "input" type as it will also be possible to choose the number of prints.
Can somebody help me and somehow guide me how to deal with it?
Thank you in advance and best regards.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! I want to ask you 2 questions, did you use relational database? And by "add a certain amount input fields" is [this](https://www.itsolutionstuff.com/post/laravel-dynamically-add-or-remove-input-fields-using-jqueryexample.html) what you looking for?

Comment: Thanks. This is what i can use :)

Comment: Oh cool! I'm glad that could help, good luck developing your Laravel App :)
I used "Dynamic input fields laravel", I hope it could help you in the future too